# Javascript/JQuery toggle not functioning IE8

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, internet-explorer-8

I have the following code which is basically a toggle.

```
function toggleContent(IDS) {
// Get the DOM reference
  var contentId = document.getElementById(IDS);
// Toggle
  contentId.style.display == 'block' ? contentId.style.display = 'none' : contentId.style.display = 'block';
}



$(function()   {
    $(document).on('click','.linky',function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        $('div.panello:visible').hide();
        $(this).next('div.panello').show();
    });
});
```

All it does is show and hide DIVS.

It works fine on any browser apart from IE8 and older. I get a javascript error "Object doesn't support this property or method".

Is there a way to adapt this to work on IE8?

EDIT: It's a dynamic toggle. The click will tell the script which id to toggle.

Comment: Have you tried [`$(contentId).toggle();`](http://api.jquery.com/toggle/)?

Comment: What version of jQuery?

Comment: If you're using jQuery 2.0 or greater then that might be the cause as jQuery 2.0 dropped support for older browsers. If that's the case and you need to support IE8 for some reason, you could try downgrading to jquery 1.11.

Comment: can u share some html code

Comment: I'm using jquery 1.10.2

Comment: <a class="linky" style="color:#666">Hello</a>  <div id="div1">class="panello"></div>

Answer (score 0):

since you are using jquery try:

```
$("'#"+IDS+"'").toggle();
```

Answer (score 0):

Try setting `display` to `inline-block` for IE8.